# Regarding calculation of atomic distances in trajectory file of GROMACS in python

Tags: python

I have a trajectory file of 100 ns (10 ns time frame ie., t=10.0, t=20.0...t=100.0) in GROMACS. How can i calculate the atomic distance by writing a python program from one atom with respect to other atom (say distance between N and all OW) for each particular time frame ie., dst b/w N and all OW when t=10.0, when t=20.0...until t=100.0 (ie., i need to calculate distance b/w N and all OW at time t=10.0, and distance b/w N and all OW at time t=20.0 etc...) and get it in a single file...

This is my trajectory file

```
Generated by trjconv : ABC t=  10.00000
    1ABC      N    1   0.134   0.731   0.816
   28SOL     OW  115   1.586   0.579   1.240
   29SOL     OW  118   0.135   0.791   1.373
   30SOL     OW  121   0.279   0.419   0.486
   31SOL     OW  124   0.185   1.369   1.168
   32SOL     OW  127   0.270   1.932   0.692
   33SOL     OW  130   1.811   1.427   0.103
   34SOL     OW  133   0.506   1.752   1.413
   35SOL     OW  136   0.067   0.943   0.328
   36SOL     OW  139   0.607   0.127   1.843
Generated by trjconv : ABC t=  20.00000
    1ABC      N    1   0.174   0.862   0.867
   28SOL     OW  115   1.835   0.664   1.072
   29SOL     OW  118   0.162   0.991   1.333
   30SOL     OW  121   1.962   0.302   0.351
   31SOL     OW  124   1.991   1.557   0.807
   32SOL     OW  127   0.371   1.974   0.575
   33SOL     OW  130   0.027   1.951   0.214
   35SOL     OW  136   0.017   0.962   0.259
   36SOL     OW  139   0.359   0.315   1.701
   .
   .
   .
Generated by trjconv : ABC t= 100.00000
    1ABC      N    1   0.436   0.482   0.720
   28SOL     OW  115   1.617   0.655   0.781
   29SOL     OW  118   0.444   1.118   0.961
   30SOL     OW  121   0.563   0.038   1.949
   31SOL     OW  124   0.101   0.983   0.321
   32SOL     OW  127   1.243   0.134   0.914
   33SOL     OW  130   0.765   1.254   0.416
   34SOL     OW  133   2.072   1.977   1.276
   35SOL     OW  136   1.030   0.726   0.400
   36SOL     OW  139   1.905   0.134   1.699
```

and i want the distance calculated between N and all OW output as :-

```
For ABC t= 10.00000
28SOL 0.47672738541
29SOL 0.442346018406
30SOL 0.353905354579
31SOL 0.416744526059
32SOL 0.4526643348
33SOL 0.28253495359

For ABC t= 20.00000
28SOL 0.4657273839
29SOL 0.5323460153
30SOL 0.16905354587
31SOL 0.65474452654
32SOL 0.5246643547
33SOL 0.98253495546
.
.
.
.
For ABC t= 100.00000
28SOL 0.1357273845
29SOL 0.2353460160
30SOL 0.15605354068
31SOL 0.56474452705
32SOL 0.5016644010
33SOL 0.240534950236
```

How can i write the python program for this...?

Thank you

Update: here is the existing script:

```
import math 
myfile=open('abc.txt', 'r') 
text=myfile.read() 
temp=text.split() 
num=len(temp) 
i=16 
while(i<num): 
    dist=math.sqrt((float(temp[i])-float(temp[10]))**2+(float(te‌​mp[i+1])-float(temp[‌​11]))**2+(float(temp‌​[i+2])-float(temp[12‌​]))**2) 
    print temp[i-3],dist 
    i=i+6 
myfile.close()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to get this done? Please show us the code you've already written.

Comment: import math
myfile=open('abc.txt', 'r')
text=myfile.read()
temp=text.split()
num=len(temp)
i=16
while(i<num):
    dist=math.sqrt((float(temp[i])-float(temp[10]))**2+(float(temp[i+1])-float(temp[11]))**2+(float(temp[i+2])-float(temp[12]))**2)
      print temp[i-3],dist
    i=i+6
myfile.close()

Comment: I moved the script to the question and it seems to be working for some iterations and then fails most probably to an incomplete trajectory file. Please post additional information about the problem with your script.

Comment: this code runs if i extract for only single time frame (ie., if i extract only for t=10.00 with the respective molecules). but i am not able to execute the code for the full trajectory..